# xpath to find value in html code

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to use xpath to get the value "National Aeronautics and Space Administration" only from the html below

```
            <table style="margin: 0 5px 0 2px; font-size: 8pt;" class="joaResultsDetailsTable">

                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Department:</strong></td>
                        <td>National Aeronautics and Space Administration</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 112px;"><strong>Agency:</strong></td>
                        <td>George C. Marshall Space Flight Center</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Open Period:</strong></td>
                        <td>9/10/2012 to 9/14/2012</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Who May Apply:</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            Current students from education institutions interested in paid opportunities wi...

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td style="vertical-align:top;"><strong>Location(s):</strong></td>

                            <td>Huntsville, Alabama</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I hope if you can help

Comment: Are you using XHTML?  If not you may need to write a schema for your document, and in the worst case, HTML will not parse as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide much context.  Any of the following XPath expressions will meet your stated requirement that the value of the expression, when evaluated against the input you show, should be the string 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration':

```
string(self::table/tr[td='Department:']/td[2])

string(self::table/tr[1]/td[2])

string(self::table/descendant::td[2]))

'National Aeronautics and Space Administration'
```

Which of these will work best for you depends on what your unstated requirements are.